# Error while adding swipe effect to listview

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to have swipe effect to my listview. BUt it shhows the following errors.

```
public class ContactsFragment extends Fragment {
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
SwipeListView lv;

ItemAdapter adapter;
List<HashMap<String, String>> fetch2 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> inboxList;

// products JSONArray
JSONArray inbox = null;

// Inbox JSON url
private static final String INBOX_URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/mail/inbox.json";

// ALL JSON node names
private static final String TAG_MESSAGES = "messages";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_FROM = "from";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String TAG_SUBJECT = "subject";
private static final String TAG_DATE = "date";



public static final String TAG = LibraryPagerAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
protected JSONArray mTasksData; 


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inbox_list, container, false);

    lv = (SwipeListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter=new ItemAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.custom_row);
    System.out.println("in on create");
    Log.d("in","Oncreate");

    lv.setSwipeListViewListener(new BaseSwipeListViewListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(int position, boolean toRight) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onClosed(int position, boolean fromRight) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onListChanged() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onMove(int position, float x) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartOpen(int position, int action, boolean right) {
            Log.d("swipe", String.format("onStartOpen %d - action %d", position, action));
        }


        public void onStartClose(int position, boolean right) {
            Log.d("swipe", String.format("onStartClose %d", position));
        }

        @Override
        public void onClickFrontView(int position) {
            Log.d("swipe", String.format("onClickFrontView %d", position));


            lv.openAnimate(position); //when you touch front view it will open


        }

        @Override
        public void onClickBackView(int position) {
            Log.d("swipe", String.format("onClickBackView %d", position));

            lv.closeAnimate(position);//when you touch back view it will close
        }

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(int[] reverseSortedPositions) {

        }

    });
    lv.setSwipeMode(SwipeListView.SWIPE_MODE_BOTH); // there are five swiping modes
    lv.setSwipeActionLeft(SwipeListView.SWIPE_ACTION_DISMISS); //there are four swipe actions 
    lv.setSwipeActionRight(SwipeListView.SWIPE_ACTION_REVEAL);
    lv.setOffsetLeft(convertDpToPixel(0f)); // left side offset
    lv.setOffsetRight(convertDpToPixel(80f)); // right side offset
    lv.setAnimationTime(500); // Animatijsonon time
    lv.setSwipeOpenOnLongPress(true); // enable or disable SwipeOpenOnLongPress

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    System.out.println(lv);
    Log.d("after","Oncreate");


    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    System.out.println(adapter);
    bindListView();

    return rootView;

}
public int convertDpToPixel(float dp) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
    return (int) px;
}


public void bindListView() {
    new LoadInbox().execute();
    System.out.println("inside bindlistview");
}


class LoadInbox extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        System.out.println("inside pre execute");
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        System.out.println("background");
        try {
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(INBOX_URL, "GET",
                    params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("Inbox JSON: ", json.toString());



            inbox = json.getJSONArray(TAG_MESSAGES);



            // looping through All messages
            for (int i = 0; i < inbox.length(); i++) {
                System.out.println(inbox.length());
                JSONObject c = inbox.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                System.out.println(id);
                String from = c.getString(TAG_FROM);

                String subject = c.getString(TAG_SUBJECT);
                System.out.println(subject);
                String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
                System.out.println(date);
                if(subject.length() > 23){
                    subject = subject.substring(0, 22) + "..";
                }
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> libraryInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();
                libraryInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                libraryInfo.put(TAG_ID, id);
                libraryInfo.put(TAG_FROM, from);
                libraryInfo.put(TAG_SUBJECT, subject);
                libraryInfo.put(TAG_DATE, date);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                fetch2.add(libraryInfo);
                System.out.println(fetch2.toString());
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try{
                    // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
                    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), fetch2, R.layout.inbox_list_item, new String[] { TAG_FROM, TAG_SUBJECT, TAG_DATE },
                            new int[] { R.id.from, R.id.subject, R.id.date });   

                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false); 
    }

    protected JSONArray doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}}
```

THIS IS MY ERROR LOG.

```
09-09 12:06:33.756: E/AndroidRuntime(24654): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-09 12:06:33.756: E/AndroidRuntime(24654): Process: com.tutecentral.swipelistviewexample, PID: 24654
09-09 12:06:33.756: E/AndroidRuntime(24654): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-09 12:06:33.756: E/AndroidRuntime(24654):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
09-09 12:06:33.756: E/AndroidRuntime(24654):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
09-09 12:06:33.756: E/AndroidRuntime(24654):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
09-09 12:06:33.756: E/AndroidRuntime(24654):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
09-09 12:06:33.756: E/AndroidRuntime(24654):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
```

Comment: is it printing message "background" and "Inbox JSON: " : your_response ?? then is it throwing an error?????

Comment: @AmolSawant96Kuli no it's not printing the message.. after printing the exception its printing the log in doinbackground "background". but not printing the json response

Comment: You have two doInBackground() functions, and both return null. Is it what you really meant?

Comment: Github sample https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview